# regex to find a string contains words with both letters and digits

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a regex to find a string contains words with both letters and digits (NOT A CHECK FOR ALPHANUMERIC because word should strictly contain both letters and digits).

I have come up with this `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])`

Here's the link to the above regex: https://regex101.com/r/Y97ykL/1

Above regex works for simple scenarios like below

1. `a1b4cc` -> true (contains both letters and digits)
2. `abc` -> false (contains only letters)
3. `123` -> false (contains only digits)

But there are few scenarios which I am not able to cover with the above regex.
How can I update my above regex to also work for the below examples?

1. `abc d77hv` -> True ( Since `efg123` contains both letter and digits)
2. `798 h7ghd` -> True (Since `h7ghd` contains both letters and digits)
3. `798 abcd` -> False (Since there is no word containing both letter and digits)

I am not too familiar with regex but is it possible to write a regex to do the check for the above described scenarios without iterating over each word in a string?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, but the whole second to last paragraph is incomprehensible for me.

Comment: i updated the examples. Is it more clear now? @MichaelButscher

Comment: Try `^(?=.*\b(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])(?=\S*[0-9]))` at https://regex101.com/r/Y97ykL/2

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Wow this is awesome. Much appreciated. Do you want to add this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `^(?=.*\b(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])(?=\S*[0-9]))` works as desired. It tries to find (with lookahead) a word boundary (`\b`) after which the requested mixture of letter(s) and number(s) can be found.

Because the original regex also only matches zero characters at the beginning of a line, this regex behaves the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find in a line a letter and a number or a number and a letter.

```
^((.*[0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]+.*)|((.*[a-zA-Z]+)[0-9]+.*)$
```

Check the examples: https://regex101.com/r/Y97ykL/3